# Align bar to the center of the chart in chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart

I have a chart with only two bars, and I want to align them to the center of the chart. Here's what I want it to look like:
[Desired Chart Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Zyb.png)
Here's what I've done so far:
[Current Chart Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq66s.png)

I've tried using categoryPercentage and barPercentage, but it's not working as expected. When I increase categoryPercentage and barPercentage, the bar width increases and goes beyond my design limits. Here's the code I've been using:

```js
var newChart = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
        newChart = new Chart(newChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: props.data.labels,
                datasets: [{
                    data: props.data.data,
                    backgroundColor: props.data.color,
                }]
            },
            plugins: [htmlLegendBarChart],
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    htmlLegend: { // custom legend
                        // ID of the container to put the legend in
                        containerID: 'bar-legend-container',
                    },
                    legend: { // hide default legend
                        display: false,
                        position: 'top'
                    },
                    tooltip: { //tooltip
                        displayColors: false, // remove color block
                        callbacks: { //format tooltip data and title
                            title: function (tooltipItem) {
                                return tooltipItem[0].label;
                            },
                            label: function (tooltipItem) {
                                return "₹" + Number(tooltipItem.formattedValue);
                            }
                        },
                        // tooltip style
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        titleColor: Colors.gray,
                        bodyColor: Colors.black,
                        titleFont: {
                            size: 12,
                            family: 'Poppins-Regular',
                            weight: 400
                        },
                        bodyFont: {
                            size: 12,
                            family: 'Inter-Medium',
                            weight: 500
                        },
                    },
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        ticks: {
                            display: false,
                            lineWidth: false,
                            drawTicks: false,
                        },
                        border: {
                            display: false,
                            dash: [8, 4]
                        },
                        grid: {
                            color: function (context) {
                                return Colors.pale_blue;

                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                categoryPercentage: 0.6,
                barPercentage: 0.6,
            },
            
        });
        return () => {
            newChart.destroy()
        }
```

How can I align these two bars to the center of the chart without exceeding my design limits?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible examle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it stands, it's hard for anyone to help you. What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried (put it in code) what is currently happening? What errors are you getting if any.

Comment: I think that what you need is to leave a margin to the left and to the right of the bars but inside the chart area. AFAIK there is no simple solution for that with category axes. One possible way is to add fake, invisible data - [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kh1e025s/); another is to hack into `scale._startValue` and `scale._valueRange` in the scale's `afterFit` handler - [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zxrkvyp1/)

Comment: @kikon Thanks for the response, both the solutions are working I will go for the second one :v